# Rails, trying run assets:precompile return "has already been required"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The first time I moved my application to production I found a few problems. I found that I should use precompiled assets in production, so I tried to compile them, but got this error:

```
rake aborted!
/var/www/tracker/app/assets/templates/snippets/comment.html.erb has already been required
  (in /var/www/tracker/app/assets/javascripts/angularjs/routes.coffee.erb)
```

The most confusing thing here is that file `comment.html.erb` is in no way mentioned in routes.coffee.erb, which simply contains a few routes for [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/):

```
angular.module('app', ['ui', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'app.filters', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'mwTable'])
  .config ['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->

    $routeProvider.when '/',
      templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('announces/list.html') %>'
      controller: AnnouncesListCtrl

    $routeProvider.when '/announce/:fid',
      templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('announces/view.html') %>'
      controller: AnnouncesViewCtrl

    $routeProvider.when '/announce/:fid/edit',
      templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('announces/edit.html') %>'
      controller: AnnouncesEditCtrl

    $routeProvider.when '/registration',
      templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('users/edit.html') %>'
      controller: UsersEditCtrl

    $routeProvider.when '/registration_successful',
      templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('users/registration_successful.html') %>'
      controller: UsersEditCtrl

    $routeProvider.when '/users',
      templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('users/list.html') %>'
      controller: UsersListCtrl

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})

  ]
```

The only thing I can think of is that I used `<%= asset_path('announces/view.html') %>`, which in turn contains `<%= asset_path('snippets/comment.html')%>`. If this causes the problem than the only solution that comes in mind is not to use `asset_path`. But is that ok to do?

Full error message is here: https://gist.github.com/SET/5167092. Despite its size, it's 99% useless.

Also, since I'm new to Rails (came from PHP), I can't understand why is it so critical that something is already required? You require it a few times but load it only once; why would this cause problems?

**UPDATE:**
I solved problem with replacing <%= asset_path(template) %>` to '/assets/template' but isn't it an ugly solution?